# Amazon Connect cases: how to determine fieldId to create case

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect, aws-sdk-net

I am new to Amazon Connect.
I am using .Net CreateCase API https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cases/latest/APIReference/API_CreateCase.html
and need to specify fields like

```
"fields": [ { "id": "string", "value": { ... } }
```

In User interface https://[AccountAccessURL]/cases/configuration/fields I can see field name and description, but not id.
Similar I wasn't able to find TemplateId in Management Console https://[AccountAccessURL]/cases/configuration/templates.

I found a workaround to get ids by calling API [ListFields](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cases/latest/APIReference/API_ListFields.html) and [ListTemplates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cases/latest/APIReference/API_ListTemplates.html)

Is it the only way to get ids or I am missing some simpler method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve got an advice from AWS Support.

When you click on Edit for a field you created(not system fields)
Field ID  can be found   at the url location:

```
https://[AccountAccessURL]/cases/configuration/fields/update/<field-Id>
```

Similar you can get Template ID at the URL when you click on Edit button on the Template.

```
https://[AccountAccessURL]/cases/configuration/templates/update/<template-Id>
```

System fields are not editable and the System field ids can be found from documentation
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/case-fields.html#system-case-fields.
For the System ones, the field-Id is usually just the name of the field in snake case .

You also can call the following AWS CLI command to get the Field-IDs of all  fields if you want to hardcode them in your code.

```
>> aws connectcases list-fields --domain-id <domain-id>
```

Finally, your workaround is also valid that you can use API calls ListFields and ListTemplates.